Java code to compare integer and string array and get the corresponding sum
There two String arrays: array1 and array2.
String[] array1 = {"1", "2", "3", "4","5","6","7"}  
String[] array2= {"apple", "", "", "banana", "", "", "orange"};

Output would be like this:
String[] desiredOutput = {"1","5","4","11","7"}

Logic: wherever there is an empty value in array2, add the corresponding values in array1
Example:
array2[0] = "apple", so desired output is value of array1[0], output ={"1"}

array2[1] = "" 

array2[2] = "" so desired output is sum of (array1[1]+array1[2]) , output ={"1","5"}

array2[3] = "banana", so desired output is value of array1[3], output ={"1","5","4"}

array2[4] = "" 
 
array2[5] = "" so desired output is sum of (array1[4]+array1[5]) ,  output ={"1","5","4","11"}

array2[6] = "orange", so the desired output value for array1[6], output ={"1","5","4","11","7"}

I have written the below logic but it's not working as expected. Trying to figure out what exact condition I have written wrong
     String[] array1 = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
     String[] array2 = {"apple", "", "", "banana", "", "", "orange"};

     // Calculate concatenated values and add them to a new array
     String[] concatenatedArray = new String[array1.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
         int value1 = Integer.parseInt(array1[i]);
         int value2 = (array2[i].isEmpty()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(array2[i]);
         concatenatedArray[i] = String.valueOf(value1 + value2);
     }

     // Print the concatenated array in the desired format
     System.out.print("(");
     for (int i = 0; i < concatenatedArray.length; i++) {
         System.out.print("\"" + concatenatedArray[i] + "\"");
         if (i < concatenatedArray.length - 1) {
             System.out.print(",");
         }
     }
     System.out.println(")");


You have to add array1[] element till you don't found non-empty element in array2[] and when this condition meet just replace last index element in result list.
I believe this is what you're looking for
    String[] array1 = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};
    String[] array2 = {"apple", "", "", "banana", "", "", "orange"};
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if(array2[i].length() > 0){
            sum=0;
            result.add(array1[i]);
        }
        else{
            if(sum != 0){
                sum += Integer.parseInt(array1[i]);
                result.set(result.size()-1, String.valueOf(sum));
            } else{
                sum += Integer.parseInt(array1[i]);
                result.add(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
        }
    }

